# Derivative of $\|\mathbf{x}(t)\|^2$ w.r.t. $t$ where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could you please suggest a way to compute the derivative of $\|\mathbf{x}(t)\|^2 $ w.r.t. $t$ where $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Just try it with the definition: $$||x||^2 = \sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \|x(t)\|^2 &= \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2 \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{d}{dt} x_j^2 \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^d 2 \ x_j(t) \left( \frac{d}{dt} x_j(t) \right) \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \| \mathbf{x}(t) \|^2 &= \frac{d}{dt} \left(x_1^2(t) + x_2^2(t) + x_3^2(t) + \dots \right) \\
&= 2 x_1(t) \frac{dx_1}{dt} + 2 x_2(t) \frac{dx_2}{dt} + 2 x_2(t) \frac{dx_2}{dt} + \dots
\end{align}